# To find a value and delete previous two records

Tags: vba, excel

I want to find the value "No Results" and remove the row and two rows above it.

```
Name 1(A1)      
  (A2 is empty)     App(B2)     Efforts (C2)

No Results(A3)
Name 3 (A4)
Valid  (A5)
Name 2(A6)
(A7 is empty)
No Results(A8)
```

I am able to remove the record were the value is, but not the records above it. Tried `Cells(i-2, "A").EntireRow.Delete` but it removes all records above it. Could you please help.

```
Sub Macro1()
    Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = Last To 1 Step -1
      If (Cells(i, "A").Value) = "No Results" Then
        Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
      End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: after you delete with proposed `Cells(i-1, "A").EntireRow.Delete` add additional line `i=i-1` inside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
Public Sub Macro1()
    Dim i As Long

    For i = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(i, "A").Value = "No Result" Then
            Range((i-2) & ":" & i).Delete
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

This works only if the sheet you want to 'filter' is the currently active sheet, if this is intended to run from a module it would be best to specify the sheet explicitly e.g. `Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "A")`.

The only real change I've made to your own attempt is the use of `Range` rather than `Cells` within your If statement. With the `Range` function we can reference an Excel range using a string e.g. `Range("A1")`. In this case specifically we construct a string referencing the rows (i-2) to i, so for `i = 9` we are executing `Range("7:9").Delete`.

Comment: Logic seems to be good, but while running the loop i end up with syntax error at ``Range((i-2) & ":" i).Delete``

Comment: My bad, there was a typo on that line, it should have read `Range((i-2) & ":" & i)`, I've edited my answer as well.